# Pascal splitting line into real and strings

Tags: file, split, line, pascal

I know that this language have died a couple of years ago, but still required in most of schools in our country -.-
I got file with data, which looks like:

- Number of lines
- Name Surname (real type digit) (another real type digit)

For e.g.

- 2
- Brat Sunbather 5.66 55.4
- Bart Simpson 55.7 45.4

And I need to create result file, which looks like this:

- Name Surname (Previously given real type digits multiplied)
- Total

For e.g.

- Brat Sunbather 313.56
- Bart Simpson 2528.78
- Total: 2842.34

I'm stuck in trying to split the line into string and real, even in the book I've given in the examples all data is on separate line:

- String
- Digit
- String
- Digit

I can't find anything on the net and hope you could help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The modern incarnation of Pascal is Delphi (on Windows and OS-X) and Lazarus on all other platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started - I got as far as reading the file, splitting the line, and converting the strings to reals:

```
Program Test;

var
    fileVar: Text;
    l: string[81];
    inputFilename: string[14];
    lCount: Integer;
    i: Integer;
    code: Integer;

    spacePos: Integer;

    firstName: string[100];
    secondName: string[100];

    num1: real;
    num2: real;
    product: real;

    s: string[100];

begin
    inputFilename := 'input.txt';
    Assign(fileVar, inputFilename);
    Reset(fileVar);

    Readln(fileVar, l);
    Val(l, lCount);

    Writeln('l count=', lCount);

    for i := 1 to lCount do
    begin
        Readln(fileVar, l);
        spacePos := Pos(' ', l);
        firstName := Copy(l, 0, spacePos);
        Delete(l, 1, spacePos);

        spacePos := Pos(' ', l);
        secondName := Copy(l, 0, spacePos);
        Delete(l, 1, spacePos);

        spacePos := Pos(' ', l);
        s := Copy(l, 0, spacePos - 1);
        Val(s, num1, code);
        Delete(l, 1, spacePos);

        Val(l, num2, code);

        WriteLn(firstName);
        Writeln(secondName);
        Writeln(num1);
        Writeln(num2);
    end;

    Close(fileVar);
end.
```

Comment: Omg, thank you so much! It so totally works! You are a life savior! Thank you, thank you so much!