# Pascal ReadLn multiple var types

Tags: variables, types, pascal, readline

***My problem looks like this.*** I got a file with data(input) "**text text number number**" on each line, I need to get data from it using ReadLn(myfile, string, string2, real1(or double), real2(or double));, as you can see in my code provided below, but when I do it with the function I've just described, **I get an error**. **I need each data in separate variable**. I need to work with numbers(multiply, sum) and I need name and surname for the output(result) file, where data will look like this "Name Surname number1(from input file) multiplied with number2(from input file)" for each line from the input file and in the last line will be "Total: sum(all lines(number1*number2))". **The only problem I need help with is to read each line data from initial file to a separate variable.**

File explanation:

- Name Surname NumericValue(***double*** type) NumericValue(***double*** type)

  E.g.:*Somedude Hissurname 86.5 9.85*

I always get an error while trying to read the line data like this:

- ReadLn(filevar(:text), name(:array of string[25]), surname(:array of
  string[25]), numeric1(:***real***), numeric2(:***real***));

  E.g.:*ReadLn(data, name[], sur[], meters, price);*

When I try same thing, but after changing numeric values to integer(in file as well):

Changes done in the file:

- Name Surname NumericValue(***integer*** type) NumericValue(***integer*** type)

  E.g. *Somedude Hissurname 86 9*

And program code looks like this:

- ReadLn(filevar(:text), name(:array of string[25]), surname(:array of
  string[25]), numeric1(:***integer***), numeric2(:***integer***));

  E.g.:*ReadLn(data, name[], sur[], meters, price);*

Program works almost as intended(numeric1 takes both numeric values and 2nd is left blank).

```
E.g.: name[] = Somedude, sur[] = Hissurname, numeric1 = 86 9, numeric2 = 0
```

Here's how far I got with my code:

```
program test;
type    mas = array[1..30] of real;
        mas1 = array[1..30] of string[25];

var name,sur:mas1;
    atl:mas;
    meters,price,total:integer;
    i,p,n       :integer;
    data      :text;
begin
    Assign(data, 'somefile.txt');
    Reset(data);
    ReadLn(data,n);
    for i:=1 to n do
        begin
                  ReadLn(data, name[i], sur[i], meters, price);
                  WriteLn(name[i],meters, price);
        end;
    Close(data);
    ReadLn;
end.
```

Thank you in advance. I've did similar post earlier, but the solution doesn't suite school needs(too complicated for them -.-) I need to use simple way of ReadLn with 4 variables in it(Or 2 or 3, if I'm wrong). In any case, forgive me for posting same problem twice.

P.S. Forgive me for formatting, spelling and idea issues. I was rather sleepy. I hope I made myself clear this time.

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the formatting. Your "trying to read data like this" is a jumbled mess, and it's simply impossible (for me, anyway) to understand. I tried formatting it for you, but since I can't comprehend it I couldn't do any reasonable formatting. Your code sample also includes code that's commented out that just adds more confusion, because your variable names are difficult for those who don't speak Lithuanian (hope I spelled that right :) ). If you can make your question clearer to read and understand, it might make it easier and quicker for you to get an answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you for notifying me and forgive for these errors.

Comment: No apologies necessary - I was trying to get you an answer more quickly, not criticizing. :) Much better formatting and question. Thanks. :) Can you edit one more time and provide a couple of sample lines from the text file you're trying to read? Also, is it necessary to read directly into arrays? Can you read into individual separate variables and then add them to the array?

Comment: "Can you edit one more time and provide a couple of sample lines from the text file you're trying to read?" I was probably doing that, while you was typing it =D - done. It doesn't matter how data added to the array, I need them only for posting to another file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your input doesn't match what you're trying to do. I wrote a quick test app: `var FirstName: string[25]; SurName: string[25]; Meters, Price: Double; TheFile: TextFile; begin FirstName := 'Ken'; SurName := 'White'; Meters := 86.5; Price := 9.85; AssignFile(TheFile, D:\TestText.txt'); Rewrite(TheFile); Writeln(TheFile, FirstName, SurName, Meters, Price); Close(TheFile); end.`. It produced (one line) `KenWhite 8.65000000000000E+0001 9.85000000000000E+0000`, which of course can't be read back using the same definitions. Care to edit one more time to explain the real question? :)

Comment: Also, more than a single line of sample data would help. Since we know they're not `string[25] string[25] double double`, and what they *actually* are can't be determined from one line, your question is almost impossible to answer. If you can't clarify it, I'm afraid I'm going to have to vote to close it as "not a real question", since you keep contradicting yourself. NOTE: Just found your other question (which you didn't link), and it conflicts with everything here as well. Make up your mind what you want, and then post a question.

Comment: It's getting to be really complicated to explain. I've edited my post, but will try to explain my problem. I have a file with some data, just imagine that it has 1 line "Name Surname numeric numeric", e.g. "Bart Simpson 5.9 86.9". I need my variables to be 1st variable = Bart, 2nd variable = Simpson, 3rd variable = 5.9, 4th variable = 86.9. When I try to get those variables with function call ReadLn(filename,1st variable, 2nd variable, 3rd variable, 4th variable); I GET AN ERROR. Where do you don't get my problem?

Comment: I've provided my code and explained everything else. Also I've told you WHY my questions differ, because my SCHOOL doesn't tolerate such high skilled code as solution given in previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering to the first paragraph for the reason Ken stated in comments to the question)

According to the [standard](http://www.standardpascal.org/iso7185.html#6.9.2%20The%20procedure%20readln) you should be able to do this. The `ReadLn` procedure can take a variable number of arguments (which only would make sense if you're able to read values into those arguments).

With two pascal compilers I can test on, this line

```
ReadLn(f, s1, s2, r1, r2);
```

compiles fine (where 'f' is a `TextFile`, 's1' and 's2' are `string`s and 'r1' and 'r2' are `Real`s).

To make it work is a bit difficult though. If you provide the below input (taken from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244797/pascal-splitting-line-into-real-and-strings)),

> Brat Sunbather 5.66 55.4

Delphi will fail with *'Invalid numeric input (EInOutError)'*, and FPC will fail with a *'Invalid Input (EInOutError)'*. The problem is with the string variables that we want to read into. The whole line we provide is in fact a string (a space is a perfectly valid character in a string), so when the code sees a string as the first variable to read into, it reads the entire line to it.

Hence, the solution is to provide a special character that would mark the end of a string. A Ctrl+Z (ASC dec:26 hex:1A) works for Delphi (I don't know what would (if anything) work for FPC or other compilers). So the specially crafted text file (for Delphi) is like:

```
2
Brat Sunbather 5.66 55.4
    ↑         ↑    ↑    ↑
   ^Z        ^Z space  eol
Bart Simpson 55.7 45.4 
    ↑       ↑    ↑    ↑
   ^Z      ^Z space  eol
```

**edit:**
If you have no control over how the input file is produced, and you're certain that a 'space' is a delimiter to a string variable, you can read the string variables character by character in a loop until you read a space. An example can be something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f: TextFile;
  fn: string;

  Lines: Integer;
  i: Integer;
  first, last: string;
  R1, R2, Total: Real;

  function ReadName: string;
  var
    c: Char;
  begin
    Result := '';
    repeat
      Read(f, c);
      Result := Result + c;
    until c = ' ';
  end;

begin
  fn := 'data.txt';
  AssignFile(f, fn);
  Reset(f);
  Read(f, Lines);
  Readln(f);
  Total := 0;
  for i := 1 to Lines do begin
    first := ReadName;
    last := ReadName;
    Read(f, R1, R2);

// do whatever necessary with names & numbers
//    showmessage(first + ' ' + last + ' - ' + FloatToStr(R1 * R2));

    Total := Total + R1 * R2;
    Readln(f);
  end;
// do whatever necessary with Total
//  ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Total));

  CloseFile(f);
end;
```

Comment: From your words, I understand, that there's only complicated solution for this matter? And ReadLn(f,str1,str2,real1,real1) won't do, right?

Comment: @Sin - If you have no control of writing the input file, then no, `ReadLn` won't do: I can't imagine a compiler that would consider 'space' a non-string character. But I wouldn't consider a `Read` loop followed by a `ReadLn` complicated.

Comment: @Sin - Updated the answer for example of reading strings character by character. See for yourself if it is complicated or not..

Comment: You are more then being aggressive, reconsider your own problems. I am beginner in Pascal(and won't ever be a pro). And your offensive behavior is more then annoying. I don't force you to help me, mind your own business. I just wanted to know if there's way to use ReadLn in my case, Sertac Had just the answer I need - no. That's all I need and what about you? Lack of cooperation? I needed a couple of programs for today, I was mega sleepy(4 am in the morning) and you were just keeping on being aggressive, after I've described my problem IN ALL WAYS POSSIBLE. Cheers and thank you Sertac.

Comment: And that's after you forced me to edit my message 20 times. 
P.S.I would flag your offensive behavior, but can't due to reputation fall, your luck you did it.

Comment: @SinSoul, I spent more than 2 hours trying to help you. Your "20 edits", which no one **forced** you to make BTW, did nothing to provide the information I asked you for while **trying to help you**; you just posted more nonsense. If you're too tired to make sense, wait until after you've slept to post your question (or start your homework earlier, before it's due the next day). Remember that you're not paying for help here - people provide it for free using their own time. No problem, though; if you think I wasn't trying hard enough to help you, I won't make the mistake again in the future.

Comment: All I've asked, why do I get error while to reading from file, using my part of code. So what did you spend hours on? In any case, thanks for help, though it wasn't provided. It was enough just to tell me, that I'm doing wrong, that this matter can't be solved in my way. My previous post had a perfect solution, but as I told. School homework must be done simple way. I've done the program myself, slightly different, but suitable way.